# how to forward https request from port 443 to another port, using Nginx

Tags: nginx, https

My server receives Https request from port 443, and I want to forward them to other ports according to the domain name. Is this feasible? How to achieve it? The certification is not in my server.

For example

```
request of https://aaa.com/ --- nginx ---> forward tcp packages to port 9001
request of https://bbb.com/ --- nginx ---> forward tcp packages to port 9002
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something that is natively supported by nginx!

What you'll need to do is create a new `server { }` block for each "upstream" service (:9001, :9002, etc), then use the `proxy_pass` rule inside that server block to forward all traffic coming from `aaa.com` to `:9001`, or whatever your case may be.

Goes something like this:

```
server {
  listen 443;
  listen [::]:443;

  server_name aaa.com www.aaa.com;
  
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9001; 
  }

  # Set https certificate variables at some point too.
}
```

Repeat the above block for `bbb.com` and swap out the location `proxy_pass` points to.

For more info, like passing headers, check out the NGINX article: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/